# how to add contact from the aplication?

Tags: iphone

i want to add contact number,name etc from the my application.Is it possible?If yes then please help me.

Comment: Yes. Please read the "Address Book Programming Guide." http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to present a user interface for the user to create a new record, use `ABNewPersonViewController`.

If you already have the data and want to save it to the address book, read Apple's [Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html) and then come back with specific questions if you encounter problems.

Comment: Hi I have one query here....I am able to add the cotacts from my application to iPhone contacts. As I am adding australian adderss the label "India" get added in address. eg. In iPhone contacts it showing Sydney Australia India instead of just Sydney Australia. Do you have any ideas